# Will the variance of some imaginary variable be negative?

Tags: statistics, complex-numbers, variance

From the formula $$\mathrm{Var}[aX]=a^2\mathrm{Var}[X],$$ if we take $a=\sqrt{-1}$ (so all measurements are pure imaginary numbers or zero), does this make the variance of $\sqrt{-1}X$ possibly negative?

Comment: I think you would define variance with the absolute value.

Comment: For complex random variables, the *covariance* is $E\left[(X-E[X])\overline{(Y-E[Y])}\right]$ and the *pseudo-covariance* is $E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])]$. Correspondingly, there are *variance* and *pseudo-variance*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_random_variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you define the variance of a complex-valued random variable. For a complex-valued random variable $Z\in\Bbb C$, if you define the variance as
$$
\mathsf{Var}Z=\mathsf E|Z-\mathsf EZ|^2
$$
then it is straightforward to show
$$
\mathsf{Var}Z=\mathsf{Var}(\Re (Z))+\mathsf{Var}(\Im (Z)).
$$
In the special case where $Z=aX$, where $X\in\Bbb R$ is a real-valued random variable and $a\in\Bbb C$ is a complex-valued scalar we obtain
$$
\mathsf{Var}Z=\mathsf{Var}(\Re (a)X)+\mathsf{Var}(\Im (a)X)=|a|^2\mathsf{Var}X,
$$
which is clearly nonnegative. Choosing $a=i$ then gives $\mathsf{Var}Z=\mathsf{Var}X$.

If, however, you define the variance using the *pseudo-variance*
$$
\mathsf{Var}Z=\mathsf E(Z-\mathsf EZ)^2
$$
then the resulting quantity will be in general complex-valued.  In our specific example
$$
\mathsf{Var}Z=\mathsf E(aX)^2-(\mathsf E(aX))^2=a^2\mathsf{Var}X.
$$
Choosing $a=i$ subsequently gives $\mathsf{Var}Z=-\mathsf{Var}X$.